# can we get all Twitter followers list and their email address in android app?

Tags: android

I have done the twitter Integraion in Android.
I need all followers list and their email addresses? is it possible?

Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get users email addresses via Twitter API due to security restrictions.
For getting followers list use this API call: [GET followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids)

Answer (score 0):

We can get all followers list and their details but personal identifiers like email and phone number do not return from twitter API. so we can't get email and phone number using twitter Api's.